# I´m using mat-tabs from angular/material but the Labels aren't shown. How can i change it so my labels are displayed?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this Template:

```
<mat-tab-group class="tasks" mat-align-tabs="center">
    <mat-tab label="Uncompleted" >
        <ng-container class="tasks" *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="task">
            <mat-card class="task" *ngIf="task.done === false">
                <mat-checkbox
                    class="example-margin"
                    [checked]="task.done" 
                    (change)="changeCompletitionState(task)"
                > 
                    {{task.description}} 
                </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-card>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

But the Labels of the Tabs aren´t displayed as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can i fix that?

Comment: maybe you are replacing the color with your custom css styles?

Comment: nope theres no css

Comment: You may be using a theme where the basic text is white. Try selecting where the labels should be to see if there is white text. If so, you need to add the `mat-app-background` class to the surrounding element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Will Alexander: "You may be using a theme where the basic text is white. Try selecting where the labels should be to see if there is white text. If so, you need to add the mat-app-background class to the surrounding element."

works for me